# Mapping 2 different results to the same key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm kinda new at this.  I have a mouse with only 3 keys that I'd like to write a script for to allow me to use the right mouse button like a "browser back" key if clicked, while still retaining the original function if held for a longer period of time.

```
RButton::
sleep 400
GetKeyState, state, RButton
if state = U
send {Browser_Back}
else
send {RButton}
keywait, RButton
return
```

Currently, all my script above does now is activates the "browser back" function, regardless of time held down.  I think there's a problem with the key being repeated at the send {RButton} line, but adding a $ to RButton:: didn't seem to help (if it was supposed to, idk.)  If I replace the 3 "RButton" instances (not including the one on the send line) with a key on the keyboard, it works perfectly though.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this may be just about what you need

```
RButton::
KeyWait, RButton, U T0.5
If !ErrorLevel
    send {Browser_Back}
else
{
    send {RButton Down}
    KeyWait, RButton
    send {RButton up}
}
return
```

Still some things you may need to fix as i did not test it for long...

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot.  I was able to get it working with some adjustments.

Comment: ohh sorry, forgot the braces, just added them to the else statement

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the code from BlackHolyMan's response to fix it.  In case anybody was curious or wanted it, here it is:

```
RButton::
KeyWait, RButton, U T0.5
If !ErrorLevel
{
    send {Browser_Back}
    return
}
else
{
    send {RButton Down}
    KeyWait, RButton
    send {RButton up}
}
return
```